# url problem with json data

Tags: json, url, twitter

For the API script of followcost.com. It is given that for using the follow cost API follow cost has a simple JSON API.

Send a GET request to followcost.com using the Twitter user name:

```
GET /lof.json
```

The server responds (formated for clarity):

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{"milliscobles_all_time":141.93,
 "average_tweets_per_day":3.01034,
 "username":"lof",
 "twitter_created_at":"2008/01/24 11:21:43 -0600",
 "at_reply_index":55.0,
 "milliscobles_recently":147.92,
 "average_tweets_per_day_recently":3.13738,
 "statuses_count":1165,
 "golden_index":3.0,
   "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/twitter_production\/profile_images\/50450572\/75756154_N00_normal.jpg"}
```

But when I use the URL `www.followcost.com/GET/Anand_Dasgupta.json` or `www.followcost.com/api/GET/Anand_Dasgupta.json` it gives *twitter user doesnt exist* error ... but I obviously have a twitter ID.

So what is the URL that I need to use?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Anand

Comment: GET is a method of the HTTP [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods ]. But you are using GET as part of the URL. URL only specifies the pathname of the file to be fetched from the server's file system and including GET as part of the pathname would be incorrect.

Comment: The GET is what happens 'behind the scenes'. Just put together the host and the part behind 'GET' and you're finished (see the answers). Another well-known method would be POST, that is, what some HTML forms do to send larger amounts of data to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

> http://followcost.com/Anand_Dasgupta.json

Answer (score 1):

yes, thats what it say in the api

> '/lof.json'
>     This means relative to site host name i.e http://followcost.com

so you can use

> http://followcost.com/Anand_Dasgupta.json